# Invoking Procedure Fails : Http request failed: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException:

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Facing following error while invoking procedure in browser and also in application. 
"Runtime: Http request failed: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: maps.googleapis.com:80 failed to respond"
   "isSuccessful": false,
   "warnings":

Connection is getting successful but invoking procedure showing error. 
Ref: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/hello-world/configuring-a-native-ios-with-the-mfp-sdk/#comment-9412

IMB MFS version : 7.1 
Xcode : 7.2
IOS : 9.2

Answer (score 0):

Your comment in the website mentions CNN but in your question you mention Google Maps. Which is it?

If you're talking about CNN then as I mentioned, you are likely using an older build of the product (and thus using an older adapter template) - CNN website changed, making the previous adapter inoperable. You need to update your installed product build and create a new adapter, which is no longer pointing to CNN.

Comment: Facing same issue for Google Maps. What to do?

Comment: maps.googleapis.com:80 gives 404 even in a browser. You're not supposed to use it maybe?